# How to override the title "ionicons-v5_logos" when I hover over the github-logo provided by ionic

Tags: html, css, ionicons

I'm trying to embed the GitHub Logo by ionic (v5) into my project which redirects to the GitHub repository of the project I made.

The logo has this annoying title "ionicons-v5_logos" which appears when I hover over the icon. How can I remove the logo's title? I've tried to remove the  logo's existing title by writing the following code in HTML (but it doesn't seem to remove the title on the ion-icon) -

```
<ion-icon name="logo-github" title="Check the code"></ion-icon>
```

I've tried to use the `aria-label`, `aria-hidden` and `ariaLabel` attributes to set/hide the title of the ion-icon, but nothing is working. Can anyone guide me to remove the title for an ion-icon?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You may disable ion-icon popup using CSS event blocking and set "title" property on parent element.

Use:

```
ion-icon {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Found here: https://github.com/palantir/blueprint/issues/2321

Comment: Note: That also prevents `(click)` events from working.

Comment: It isn't preventing my click events.  Works great!

Comment: its preventing click event as well

Comment: Wrap the icon in a div and assign that div the click functionality to make `pointer-events: none` work without blocking click events.

Answer (score 3):

You can try using **ion-icon** inside **ion-button** and add the **(click)** function on ion-button like this:

```
<ion-button (click)="yourFunction()">
     <ion-icon name="close"></ion-icon>
</ion-button>
```

You won't see the title on hover anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I have an answer! You can go to the releases of Ionicon on GitHub (https://github.com/ionic-team/ionicons/releases?page=2) and see that  v5.2.0 has added title.You can use older versions. You can import v5.1.2 (for better results) by  eliminating 5.5.2 in the installation script (that you added in your project for using Ionicons).

```
//Use this code

<script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.1.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>

<script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.1.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>
```